# react-native run-android FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, react-native

When I use the react to build an Android app,runing "react-native run-android". It show me that :

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

in the main directory of your project, try:

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, where I have use "native" as the project name. When I changed the name with "TestRN" & run "react-native run-android", the project has worked in Android emulator.